# Parent Element Bounding Box Relative to Child Element

Tags: html, css, parent

Ok I've been wanting to ask another question here for some time. I hope this is simple enough and not a repeat...

So I have a list item list with some anchor tags nested inside of them...

```
<ul class="news">
<li><a href="#">This Link is Longer</a></li>
<li><a href="#">My Links</a></li>
</ul>
```

like those.

As you can see the first anchor tag's text is longer than the anchor tag below, in that there are more characters present.

I have a background-color on my list items however I would like the background-color/bounding box for each list item to be only as WIDE as the anchor tag within it, it being a list item...(disregard margin and padding)

I have my unordered list area set with a max-width of 40% as it is a piece of a float that is nested inside of a parent div...

```
ul.news {
    max-width: 40%;
    float: right;
}

ul.news li {
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    background-color: rgba(57,14,99,1.0);
    padding: 7px;
}
```

IN SHORT

The background box is setting to the length of the biggest anchor tag. In this example, my link "My Links", has a purple box around it that is as large or as long as the link above it, "This Link is Longer". I will most likely kick myself, but how would I, using CSS, set my li width (I'm assuming width) relative to it's anchor child's size... "My Links" should have a purple box only as big as "My Links" extends (plus 7px padding on each side,of course).

THANK YOU for your helllppp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the list items float too

```
ul.news li {
    float: right;
}
```

**[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8m7BC/1/)**

Comment: Wow. Bingo. Simple things like that seem to fly past my mind. Thanks!

Comment: @Brkonnia You're welcome, don't forget to mark the answer as "accepted" if it resolved your issue

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
        ul.news {
            max-width: 40%;
            float: right;
        }

        ul.news li{
            text-align: right;
            margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
            padding: 7px 0px 7px 0px;
        }

        ul.news li a{
            padding: 7px;
            background-color: rgba(57,14,99,1.0);
        }
```